# Rails - Simple Search with multiple parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

For my application, I have implemented a simple search for projects via the tutorial [HERE](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form).

I am searching for projects, but I want to search for only projects that is true for a certain attribute.

If you see below, I have two items:

```
    1) where('projecttitle LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    2) where(:reviewed => true)
```

The first one is the column in the table being searched. But I want to search only columns for the projects where the attribute "reviewed == true" . How do I do this?

Thanks.

**project.rb**

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('projecttitle LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    # where(:reviewed => true)
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following and got it to work.

project.rb

```
scope :approved,  where(:projectreviewed => true)
```

projects_controller.rb

```
def index
  @projects = Project.search(params[:search]).approved.page(params[:page]).per_page(8)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you actually need a search method like this in your model unless it's being used elsewhere. Having said that, I would think something like the following in your controller would work. Note: I have not reviewed the tutorial.

```
def YOUR_CONTROLLER_ACTION_NAME_HERE
  if params[:search]
    @projects = Project.where("reviewed = ? and projecttitle LIKE %?%", true, params[:search])
  else
    @projects = Project.all
   end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work with: `where('projecttitle LIKE ? AND reviewed = ?', "%#{search}%", true)` ... But what if I want to add another `projectdescription LIKE ?` ? would it be `where('projectdescription LIKE ? OR projecttitle LIKE ? AND reviewed = ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", true)` ?